# Firebase testlab for Flutter app always gives timeout

Tags: flutter, automated-tests, android-instrumentation, firebase-test-lab, flutter-integration-test

In my flutter app I did all the integration steps to run a test lab test

I created MainActivityTest.java, and updated the **build.gradle** with the test dependencies

I created the integration test directory and the driver

Then I used the following command to generate apks

```
 pushd android 
flutter build apk ./gradlew app:assembleAndroidTest ./gradlew app:assembleDebug -Ptarget=integration_test/<name>_test.dart $ popd
```

then I uploaded them into the testlab,

it is always gives timeout
[image]
Can anyone please suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your all tests total execution time taking longer time to execute which is more than 45 min on physical device,It also indicated in your screenshots error message,  your tests will timeout in firebase test lab because FTL has limit for that. Refer below firebase test lab document:
[https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/get-started#:~:text=Note%20that%20all%20test%20types,Espresso%20or%20UI%20Automator%20frameworks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/get-started#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20all%20test%20types,Espresso%20or%20UI%20Automator%20frameworks).
**all test types are limited to running 45 minutes on physical devices and 60 minutes on virtual devices.**

**Note**: So make sure your all tests execution time is less than 45 min if you running tests on physical devices and less than 60 min if tests are being run on virtual devices(emulators etc)